# Network Modularity Calculations in R

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, modularity

The equation for [Network Modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_%28networks%29) is given on its wikipedia page (and in reputable books).  I want to see it working in some code.  I have found this is possible using the [modularity library](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/modularity.html) for [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) used with R ([The R Foundation for Statistical Computing](http://www.r-project.org/)).

I want to see the example below (or a similar one) used in the code to calculate the modularity.  The library gives on example but it isn't really what I want.

Let us have a set of vertices  V = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and edges E = {(1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5) (3,5)} that form an undirected graph.

Divide these vertices into two communities: c1 = {2,3} and c2 = {1,4,5}.  It is the modularity of these two communities that is to be computed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph(c(1,5,2,3,2,4,2,5,3,5))
membership <- c(1,2,2,1,1)
modularity(g, membership)
```

Some explanation here:

1. The vector I use when creating the graph is the edge list of the graph. (In igraph versions older than 0.6, we had to subtract 1 from the numbers because igraph uses zero-based vertex indices at that time, but not any more).
2. The *i*-th element of the membership vector `membership` gives the index of the community to which vertex *i* belongs.

Comment: Thank you Tamás.  How did you come up with `membership <- c(1,2,2,1,1)` exactly?  I'm probably not reading it correctly but for the first edge (1,5), you've said community 1 but vertices 1 and 5 are in community 2?

Comment: Yes, I mixed that up; in my vector, vertices 1, 4 and 5 belong to community 1 and vertices 2 and 3 belong to community 2.

Comment: Be careful, the membership vector must be zero based (according to the documentation)

Comment: @Pomber: actually, it doesn't matter since the modularity formula only cares about whether two vertices belong to the same community or not, so it is safe to shift the membership vector by any arbitrary constant. However, it is true that igraph functions always *return* a zero-based membership vector.

Comment: Perhaps the newer iGraph library has changed some things but the above graph `g` yields an error when being instantiated. And, contrary to comments above, the membership vector must now be 1-based according to the docs (http://igraph.org/r/doc/modularity.html)

Comment: Yes, the R interface of igraph changed from 0-based indexing to 1-based indexing to be more consistent with the rest of R, since igraph 0.6. I'll update the post.